# MySQL workbench 6.2 auto-increment

Tags: mysql

The problem is I have `class_id,faculty_id,course_id,semester,day and time` records in `class` table. The `class_id` in this table is auto-incremented, `faculty_id` and `course_id` are also auto_incremented in there own respective tables.

My question is, when I insert values of semester, `day` and `time` I want the rest of the three ids(`class_id,faculty_id and course_id`) to be auto-incremented. I tried it with the help of triggers but it is not incrementing all the records together but it is incrementing one after the other.

Here are the queries used:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER classINSERT AFTER INSERT ON `faculty` FOR EACH ROW
begin insert into class(faculty_id) values(new.faculty_id);
end

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER classINSERT2 AFTER INSERT ON `course` FOR EACH ROW
    begin insert into class(course_id) values(new.course_id);
    end
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? you would not create new course by entering semester, day and time but you would select/link the existing course_id as a foreign key..

Comment: I can make it a foreign key but auto-increment doesn't work for both the records.

Comment: you said " it is incrementing one after the other" so it means its working? you cannot expect class_id, course_id, faculty_id to have same value. One table might start incrementing from 1 other table might do it from 3 depends on whether records deleted or not.

Comment: ya it is incrementing once you enter the values in faculty or course tables. If the faculty_id is triggered to the `class` table the `course_id` is shown as null. I'm not expecting all the values to be same. Its okay even if the values are distinct but I want it to be auto-incremented.

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER classINSERT2 AFTER INSERT ON `course` FOR EACH ROW
    begin insert into class(course_id) values(new.course_id);
    end

Comment: This is a trigger used to insert `course_id` into the `class` table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are mis interpreting the word "auto-increment" and its function with your current needs. From your two triggers i see you are trying to insert a new record into the tbl_class table when a new faculty/course is created.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER classINSERT AFTER INSERT ON `faculty` FOR EACH ROW
begin 
    insert into class(faculty_id) values(new.faculty_id);
end
```

above code tells me after insert on tbl_faculty insert a new record in to the tbl_class with newly created faculty_id. There is no sign of course_id. of course it will show as blank/null if you don't set it.

the same applies for the other trigger.

I'm not sure if this thats is your intention but AFAIK this does not make any sense. The tbl_class should be created with existing faculty_id and course_id probably a drop-down-box in  your form.

in case if you want to create new course or new faculty while creating a new class record. that is completely different question from what you are asking now. That would require a new form taking the new faculty name and perform an insert on the table and refresh the drop-down-box.